# Boy and babysitter are terrorized by life sucking vacuum

Tags: story-identification

I have been looking for this TV Show | Movie for the longest time. From what I can remember it was in black and white and it's style was very similar to that of *The Twilight Zone* and *The Other Limits*. I have looked through a ton of old TV series and nothing has been even close.

**NOTE**: It may have been a movie.

From recollection: A young boy has a new babysitter to watch him while his parents are away. The boy has interest in engineering and has many gadgets in his room. One of those gadgets looks very similar to a vacuum cleaner from those times. The vacuum cleaner like device is turned shortly after the babysitter arrives.

The boy and the babysitter then figure out that the vacuum cleaner is sucking the 'life force' out of objects. It detects the object by sound then sucks on it until it no longer produces sound. This is true for both inanimate and animate objects. The vacuum cleaner sucks the 'life force' out of every thing in the house leaving it dark and silent. In the end the boy and babysitter are sitting in the closest hiding from it, but it detects their heart beats.

This is all I can remember from it. I want to watch it again, as I do not remember the ending.

Thank you in advance to anyone able to assist me with finding this movie or TV show.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To me, this sounds similar to *[Hush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Tales_from_the_Darkside_episodes#Season_4_.281987-1988.29)*, the 18th episode of Season 4 of *[Tales from the Darkside](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_the_Darkside)*.

It's about a boy who creates a vacuum cleaner to suck the sound out of things, which it does by killing them (or in the case of inanimate objects powered by batteries, killing the batteries). Specifically, I believe the boy says that the vacuum cleaner kills by sucking out the life force of living things after the vacuum kills one of his pets.

The main thing that doesn't match though, is that the episode itself is in color, and it's not a movie.

Comment: OMG. This is the episode I was look forever for. I do remember it being wedged in that time of late night tv where they mixed the color and non-color oldies. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

'Hush' was originally a short story by Zenna Henderson. It's printed in her book-'The Anything Box'.

Comment: This book has already been suggested, do you have additional information about why it fits?